# How to get all columns when you do group by for multiple columns?

Tags: sql, asp.net

Here is my table

```
    UserDetail

Id  UserId CourseId  SubjectId TeacherCode   RDate        status
 1  1      1          1         1          08/02/2016     Waiting
 2  1      1          1         2          08/01/2016     Recceived
 3  1      1          1         3          08/02/2016     Processed
 4  1      1          2         1          08/03/2016     Recceived
 5  1      1          2         2          08/04/2016     Processed
 6  1      2          1         3          08/05/2016     Processed
 7  1      2          2         1          08/06/2016     Processed
```

User can have multiple courses,multiple subjects.One teacher can teach multiple subject.I want to fetch all column from table, base on distinct userid,courseid and subjectid.Out of 7 row,want to show only 4 rows.
Any one record from below

```
Id  UserId CourseId  SubjectId TeacherCode   RDate        status
 1  1      1          1         1          08/02/2016     Waiting
 2  1      1          1         2          08/01/2016     Recceived
 3  1      1          1         3          08/02/2016     Processed
```

If we pick teachercode 1,then rdate to be  08/02/2016  and status to be Waiting
neither Recceived nor Processed.
Any one from below

```
Id  UserId CourseId  SubjectId TeacherCode   RDate        status
4   1      1          2         1          08/03/2016     Recceived
5   1      1          2         2          08/04/2016     Processed
```

How to do that?

Comment: Why teacherid in the userdetails table?

Comment: Table is already created by some one.I can not change it.

Comment: You should look up the following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: I didnt get the part from "if we pick teacher code ...." To the last of your question. You want a distinct by those three colmuns ? Just this ?

Comment: You mean you want the first one from any distinct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta know which rows of that distincted datas you want to choose. First rows ? Last rows ?

Since for every group of distincted data would be multiple rows so you mist choose which row you want.

I assume you want the first row from every distincted group. You can do it like below:

```
Select first(Id) AS Id, first(UserId) AS UserId, first(CrouseId) AS CourseId, first(SubjectId) AS SubjectId, first(TeacherId) AS TescherId,first(RDate) AS RDate, first(status) as status
FROM UserDetail
Group By UserId, CourseId, SubjectId
```

In sql2005+, do it like below:

```
 WITH temp AS  (
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId,CourseId,SubjectId ORDER BY Id) AS rn FROM UserDetail)
SELECT t.*
FROM temp t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Or you can do it using inner select instead of WITH:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId,CourseId,SubjectId ORDER BY Id) AS rn FROM UserDetail)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi Amir Ziarati,I am using sql server 2012.I am getting error while executing query.error is ''first' is not a recognized built-in function name.'

Comment: Use "Top 1 columnName" instead ;)

Comment: I used like this.Query : SELECT top 1 [Id]
      ,[UserId]
      ,[CourseId]
      ,[SubjectId]
      ,[TeacherCode]
      ,[RDate]
      ,[status]
  FROM [dbo].[UserDetail]
group by [UserId]      ,[CourseId]       ,[SubjectId]
order by id 
But I am getting error.I have to take all column in group by or in aggregate function

Comment: I updated the answer check it and let me know if there is any problem ;)

Comment: Thanks Amir for ur help.I have used like this.Query : 
SELECT *
  FROM (
                SELECT  [UserId],[CourseId],[SubjectId],[TeacherCode],[RDate],[status],
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [UserId],[CourseId],[SubjectId] ORDER BY [UserId],[CourseId],[SubjectId]) rn
                FROM [UserDetail]
              ) a
WHERE rn = 1.Why u use checksum here?

Comment: From what i remember "partition by" wouldnt accept more than one column :/ well donw you did it great. Using inner select instead of with(...)